# How do I determine the distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The question is as follows:

Let $X_1, . . . , X_{2n}$ be a random sample of $2n$ observations
from a standard normal distribution. Let $Y=\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ denote the average of the first $n$ observations $X_1, . . . , X_n$ and
let $Z =\frac1n \sum_{i=n+1}^{2n} X_i$ denote the average of the remaining observations $X_{n+1}, . . . , X_{2n}$.
Determine the distribution of $\frac{Y}{|Z|}$.

Comment: Ok, so you first need some idea of the distributions of $Y$ and $Z$. Do you have these?

Comment: Since $Y,Z\sim N(0,1/n)$ independently,$$\frac{Y}{|Z|}=\frac{\sqrt{n}Y}{\sqrt{(\sqrt{n}Z)^2/1}}\sim t_1$$by definition of the $t$-distribution.